# Issue in converting currency in bidirectional

Tags: javascript, java, converters, currency

I want to convert the value from source currency to target and target to source currency by taking standard currency conversion master. Here is the conversion master data.

1. EUR-USD=>`1.09670`
2. USD-EUR=>`0.911829`

For some values, I am not getting the accurated value when converting from EUR to USD and vice versa.

If my value is `142209.92`, then

1. Converting from EUR to USD is : `155961.619264`
2. Converting from USD to EUR is : `142210.3273318739`

So the initial value 142209.92 doesn't matched with the output `142210.3273318739`.

Is there any way to solve this kind of issues?

Rounding and fixing decimal values are also not helped me. 
Currently am doing the conversion in javascript and it can be fine to write in java too.
Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your two exchange rates are not direct inverses of each other.
If you want the exact same amount, your USD/EUR rate should exactly match `1/1.09670` which is `0.91182638825568`

If you use these two values you get the correct results:

```
142209.92 * 1.09670 =  155961.619264

155961.619264 * 0.91182638825568 = 142209.92000000060525
```